# Is it possible to MongoTemplate.updateFirst() using Jackson @JsonAnySetter Mapped Model?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jackson, mongotemplate

I'm using Jackson to map random XML fields into MongoDB (which works great).  The class is:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "event")
public class NextEvent {
@Id
public String id;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}   
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="key")
public String key;
public String getKey() {
    return key;
}
public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}
private Map<String, String> event = new TreeMap<String, String>();
@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, String> get() {
    return event;
}
@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String name, String value) {
    event.put(name, value);
}
}
```

My issue is how to come up with a creative way to update the documents using MongoTemplate.updateFirst() based on the key field.  I don't want to alter the id, but I'd like to update any other fields.  The fields are random (hence using Map for getters and setters); so, updating fields individually is not an option.

I've played around with the method below, but to no avail; any thoughts?  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    public void updateNextEvent2(NextEvent event) {
    DBObject userDBObject = (DBObject) mongoTemplate.getConverter().convertToMongoType(event);      
    BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery("{ 'key' : '" + event.getKey() + "' }");
    Update setUpdate = Update.fromDBObject(new BasicDBObject("$set", userDBObject));
    mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, setUpdate, NextEvent.class);      
    }
```

Comment: Solved it going a different route than Update/Query:

    mongoTemplate.getDb().getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME).update(new     
        BasicDBObject("key",event.getKey()), new BasicDBObject
        ("$set", userDBObject), false, false);

Answer (score 0):

Solved it going a different route than Update/Query:

```
mongoTemplate.getDb().getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME).update(new 
BasicDBObject("key",event.getKey()), new BasicDBObject ("$set", userDBObject), false, false);
```